# Improved Grab and multiple Natural Weapons

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, grapple

Let us take a tiger as an example of a creature having solid chances of making full attack with multiple Natural Weapons each of which may be used to trigger Improved Grab. Let us also assume it hits on each attack for simplicity.
How exactly whole attack sequence will look like if given tiger wins grapple check on its first (or second) claw attack? Would it be than entitled to its remaining attacks? <sup>1</sup>
In extension, how about Rake attacks?
From one hand if a tiger attacks with a Charge, he would be entitled to two Rake attacks all tigers have thanks to Pounce ability. From the other hand, Rake says it can't be done in the same round as a hold <sup>2</sup>. So if there is a hold during full attack it should cancel Rakes for that particular turn. Am I right, or hold cancels only Rakes "obtained" through that hold?

---

1* As I see it, if a creature allowed only single Natural Weapon attack in a grapple per turn, a successful hold should ruin subsequent attacks because that creature is now in a grapple. And it have attacked at least once already.
2* Improved Grab (but strangely only in stat blocks) states: "If it [monster] wins the grapple check, it establishes a hold and can rake." It seems "... in the subsequent rounds" clause is missing there, as there is almost no chance that Rake would be used not through Improved Grab but through regular grapple. So why even bother to add this "it [monster] can’t begin a grapple and rake in the same turn" clause in Rake description, if most common way to use Rake cancels that clause anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Setup

Abe, a human Clr4 of Nobanion, has been tasked by his superiors to apprehend a man-eating tiger. He expended his spells traveling to the tiger's lair. The tiger, smelling the meat juice Abe bathed in before his trip, thinks Abe a potentially tasty snack. (*Note:* The tiger is correct.)

### Round 1

Abe is between 10 ft. and 80 ft. from the tiger, which has an unimpeded route to him.

1. Abe and the tiger make initiative checks. The tiger goes first.
2. The tiger takes a full-round action to make a [charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge).
3. Due to its special ability [pounce](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#pounce), at the end of the charge the tiger makes a full attack.<sup>1</sup>
4. The tiger makes an attack with its claw, hitting and dealing damage.
5. Due to its special ability [improved grab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#improvedGrab), the tiger attempts to start a [grapple](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grapple) without provoking an attack of opportunity and without needing to make a touch attack, hence advancing immediately to Step 3: Hold.
6. The tiger and Abe make opposed grapple checks.
7. The tiger wins, getting a hold on Abe. Due to the tiger's special ability [improved grab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#improvedGrab), the tiger does *not* deal its unarmed strike damage, and the tiger moves Abe into its space.
8. Because If You're Grappling says

   > If your base attack bonus allows you multiple attacks, you can attempt one of these actions in place of each of your attacks, but at successively lower base attack bonuses.

   the tiger's base attack bonus means it can't make more attacks this way and is unable to use immediately, for example, the options Attack Your Opponent or Damage Your Opponent.
9. The tiger makes two rake attacks against Abe. The tiger's special ability pounce says that

   > If a tiger charges a foe, it can make a full attack, including two rake attacks.

   Normally, [rake](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#rake) attacks have all kinds of restrictions placed on them, but when a *tiger* charges and makes a full attack, that full attack includes the two rake attacks, no matter the usual limitations of [rake](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#rake), specific overriding general. The tiger, despite having grappled its foe this turn, *has* charged and made a full attack, so it makes its rake attacks.<sup>2</sup>

   *Note:* This is where the argument starts. A player whose character gets raked in the first round by a tiger grappling him will undoubtedly, if allowed, flip to the *Monster Manual* on [rake](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#rake), read that, and argue in favor of not getting raked. It's up to the DM if general should instead override specific here, but doing so substantially weakens the tiger as a threat, and the tiger's pounce is *awfully* specific. The only comparison I can make is that if the tiger's pounce said the tiger could instead, for example, breathe fire or sting a creature after that *including*, would the player be okay with that? The specific rules would be overridden in those cases, too. But I can easily imagine a dispirited player whose character was just tiger-mauled taking exception to the printed text, claiming the DM made a bad call, and departing the table in a huff. In a tigercentric campaign, the DM should establish early whether the pouncing-raking tiger reading is the correct one for his table, and, if it is, the DM should make sure the players know ahead of time that, perhaps, tigers are not to be trifled with by low-level characters.

On his turn, Abe takes a standard action to attempt to escape the tiger's grapple. He and the tiger make opposed grapple checks. The tiger wins.<sup>3</sup>

### Round 2

The tiger decides it wants to beef up its reputation as a man-killer and tries to kill Abe.

1. The tiger and Abe make opposed [grapple](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grapple) checks, the tiger taking the option Damage Your Opponent.
2. The tiger wins. According to the special ability [improved grab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#improvedGrab), as the tiger has made a successful grapple check, it deals its claw damage as that's the attack that established the hold. Because of its successful grapple check, it *also* deals Abe 1d4+6 nonlethal damage, equivalent to its unarmed strike damage. Note that the tiger still lacks a base attack bonus sufficient to make multiple attacks this way during a grapple. Further, the tiger could've gotten cocky and suffered a -4 penalty to the opposed grapple check when it took the Damage Your Opponent option to deal Abe lethal damage instead of nonlethal damage.
3. As this is the second round of grappling, the tiger can now make two [rake](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#rake) attacks normally.

The tiger will likely continue this process until Abe or it is unconscious, dead, or something (possibly divine) intervenes.

---

**Notes**
<sup>**1**</sup> [Most DMs rule that the full attack replaces instead of supplements the attack at the end of the pounce.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62770/8610)
<sup>**2**</sup> This exception was *slightly* clearer in the *Monster Manual* for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*: "If the tiger pounces on an opponent, it can also rake," but this really only clarifies things a little bit.
<sup>**3**</sup> Note that the tiger made a grapple check, and, according to the special ability [improved grab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#improvedGrab), "each successful grapple check [the creature] makes during *successive rounds* automatically deals the damage indicated for the attack that established the hold" (emphasis mine). Luckily for Abe, it's still the same round in which the hold was established.

Comment: Thanks for detailed and well-arranged answer. However I disagree with some statements, so let us wait for another answers or comments/upvotes that approve your point.

Comment: @annoyingimp Seriously, I welcome your dissent. The writing is sloppy enough on the topic that we can *both* seem right yet still disagree.

Comment: Would you not have the Tiger only start the grapple on it's second claw attack or would you argue that, that is too 'tactical' of thinking for an animal? 

However, I will give you a +1 for pointing out that grappling 'interrupts' the normal attack flow. For example, it is very common for druids at my table to do all their attacks and afterwards grapple, even if the grapple is initiated by the 'primary' attacks (I never thought about it before).

Comment: @BasJansen Against a lone foe, the tiger wins by getting into a grapple as fast as it can, and it may miss with that second claw attack. (There's an argument for letting the tiger bite *first* then make its claw attacks (technically allowed because the tiger's not getting multiple attacks due to its base attack bonus), but that's not what real tigers do and seems to be violating the spirit of the tiger's *Monster Manual* entry.) (Also, with those house rules, your druids' turns must take *forever!*)

Comment: They do, although I would not call it a house rule as we just never really did attacks in sequence but just threw a bunch of dice at the same time (for all attacks) and therefore, the fact that grapple stops the full attack sequence was missed. I am going to have a fun time discussing this with my group during the next session *shrug*.

Comment: @HeyICanChan According to the rules of the game, part 2, I think that the tiger would still be allowed to make his second claw and bite attack albeit at a -4 to-hit. The net result would be a round that goes claw 1 (no penalty) -> grapple attempt, claw 2 (at -4 if grappling, otherwise new grapple attempt), bite (at -4 if grappling), 2x rakes (not sure if these get -4 if grappling).

Comment: @BasJansen The Rules of the Game articles are notorious for their subtle errors. The the phrase "When you **begin your turn** involved in a grapple (no matter who started the grapple), you have several options" (emphasis mine) is, for example, in the *PH*, "When you are grappling (regardless of who started the grapple), you can perform any of the following actions..." (*PH* 156). It's totally cool if you want to start another question, though.

Comment: Why is the damage nonlethal? Only monks get the exception, not other creatures that can do lethal damage with an unarmed strike?

Comment: @Wyrmwood I'm unsure of the question. Creatures normally deal nonlethal damage with [unarmed strikes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/weapons.htm#unarmedStrike). The tiger could've elected to deal lethal damage instead by taking the -4 penalty on its grapple check, but, as complex as this already is, I tried to keep things as simple as I could.

Comment: An exception is called out under Damage Your Opponent for Monks. I have always assumed this exception applied to any creature that normally dealt lethal damage with unarmed strikes or natural weapons.

Comment: There are also many creatures with "Weapon Finesse" and only natural attacks. It would be inconsistent to apply Natural Attack <==> Unarmed Strike in one case, but not another.

Comment: @Wyrmwood The full text as per the *PH* is as follows: "If you win, you deal nonlethal damage as normal for your unarmed strike (1d3 points for Medium attackers or 1d2 points for Small attackers, plus Strength modifiers). If you want to deal lethal damage, you take a –4 penalty on your grapple check" (156). I don't know why you'd assume the monk exception universal: "Monks deal more damage on an unarmed strike than
other characters, and the damage is lethal...." (ibid.) I honestly have no idea what the feat Weapon Finesse has to do with this.

Comment: Because all creatures with natural attacks "deal more damage on an unarmed strike than other characters, and the damage is lethal". Are all natural attacks nonlethal, or only when damaging in a grapple? Honestly, I've never seen it played that way, but I can see the logic you followed to get there.

Comment: @Wyrmwood To be fair, I've never seen it played *your* way either, *and* I'm having a lot harder time wrapping my brain around monks being, like, a *metaphor* for tigers than I ever had with monks just being, like, only *monks*. `:-)` If you think this is worth a question, though, you really should ask it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31337/discussion-between-wyrmwood-and-hey-i-can-chan).